# What does it mean to have a block of c++ code with a backslash after each semicolon?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have recently seen blocks of C++ code where there is a "\" after each semicolon. It seems very odd to me. Perhaps it is nothing more than a mistake or the remnants of some long forgotten comments (although those have a forward slash "/" ). What impact would this "\" have on the code?

Her is a code sample.

```
#define PE_DECLARE_CLASS(class_) \
typedef class_ MyClass; \
static void setSuperClasses(); \
```

Comment: Can you show an example usage?

Comment: Probably a multiline macro.

Comment: ...and if it's not a multi-line macro, it probably started as one, but got expanded inline via copy-n-paste, when somebody heard that macros were evil.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A backslash as last character in a line causes this line to be joined with the next for preprocessing. For regular C++ parsing newlines are simply whitespace, so this does not matter. But preprocessor directives, in particular macro definitions end at the end of line.

Using a backslash for line continuation allows formatting long macro bodies across multiple source text lines.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping me! I never made the connection that it was happening near macros. So does that allow this macro to contain function commands? I'm not used to anything more than simple macro definitions.

Comment: what if it's not a macro?

Comment: when defining a long macro, is it problematic if we omit the back slash and just change the line?