# backslash usage in C language

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, backslash

what does backslash work if it is not followed by anything in C language?
I add "\" after the break of "case 'a'" but it takes no effect for anything. So what does "\" here do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return (-1);

    char test = argv[1][0];

    switch (test) {
        case 'a':
            printf("good\n");
            break; \
        case 'b':
            printf("bad\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash can be used to escape a newline in source code so that two lines are treated as a single line.

In your particular case it has no effect on the code, however it's more commonly used in macros which end at the time a newline is reached, i.e.:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x) \
    do {\
        int y;\
        y = foo();\
        x = y;\
    } while (0)
```

Here the backslashes are required, otherwise only the first line would be part of the macro.

Answer (score 4):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570370/11691249).

A backslash as the last character in a line causes this line to be joined with the next for preprocessing. For regular C parsing newlines are simply whitespace, so this does not matter. But preprocessor directives, in particular, macro definitions end at the end of the line.

Using a backslash for line continuation allows formatting long macro bodies across multiple source text lines.

Answer (score 4):

From the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A
>      source ﬁle that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which
>      shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any
>      such splicing takes place.

SO these two physical lines

```
        break; \
    case 'b':
```

mean one logical line

```
        break; case 'b':
```