# What is the function of a \ between two strings in a C language definition?

Tags: c, json, string

I have a JSON object in a definition as follows:

```
#define REGISTRER_DEVICE      \
"{"                           \
"\"Type\":1"                  \
","                           \
"\"Uid\":\"92a5aa89c771de67\""\
","                           \
"\"Port\":6787"               \
","                           \
"\"TypeConn\":0"              \
                              \
"}"
```

My intention is to stop using a #define to put the information in an array of type char, but I don't understand is what does the \ between each string do.

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Regards

Comment: It masks the newline, making the compiler only see 'one command line'.

Comment: Do you know what value this assigns to `REGISTER_DEVICE`?  That would give you a big clue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570297/995714

Comment: @RefugnicEternium this is a #define, so _compiler_ never sees the line. It's handled by _pre-processor_

Comment: It's an escape sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: @FiddlingBits no, in this case it's the preprocessor's escape character and has nothing to do with C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `\` is immediately followed by a new-line character<sup>1</sup> in the source code, both are removed logically so that the next physical line of source code is logically joined to the current line. This happens at an early phase of the compilation (translation phase 2 in the C standard), before preprocessor directives such as `#define` are processed (at translation phase 4).

Logically, preprocessor directives such as `#define` begin and end on a single logical line, so `\` can be used to split the directive over several physical lines.

In OP's example code:

```
#define REGISTRER_DEVICE      \
"{"                           \
"\"Type\":1"                  \
","                           \
"\"Uid\":\"92a5aa89c771de67\""\
","                           \
"\"Port\":6787"               \
","                           \
"\"TypeConn\":0"              \
                              \
"}"
```

The physical lines are joined into a single logical line:

```
#define REGISTRER_DEVICE      "{"                           "\"Type\":1"                  ","                           "\"Uid\":\"92a5aa89c771de67\""","                           "\"Port\":6787"               ","                           "\"TypeConn\":0"                                            "}"
```

Each non-empty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line might be replaced (at translation phase 3) by a single space, or it might not. It is implementation-defined. For clarity, the replacement would result look like this:

```
#define REGISTRER_DEVICE "{" "\"Type\":1" "," "\"Uid\":\"92a5aa89c771de67\"""," "\"Port\":6787" "," "\"TypeConn\":0" "}"
```

The expansion of the `REGISTRER_DEVICE` macro consists of a sequence of concatenated string literals. If the macro is expanded somewhere in the source code (during translation phase 4), that sequence of concatenated string literals in the expansion will be converted (during translation phase 6) to the equivalent single string literal:

```
"{\"Type\":1,\"Uid\":\"92a5aa89c771de67\",\"Port\":6787,\"TypeConn\":0}"
```

That string literal contains backslash escape sequences and encodes the following null-terminated sequence of characters, which is the JSON object source:

```json
{"Type":1,"Uid":"92a5aa89c771de67","Port":6787,"TypeConn":0}
```

(There is a null terminator at the end of the array of characters represented by the string literal to mark the end of the string. This null terminator is not shown above and is not part of the JSON source for the object.)

---

<sup>1</sup> The end of line sequence in the physical source file will have been mapped to the new-line character during translation phase 1 in the C standard. For example MS-DOS/Windows text files mark the end of line with an (ASCII) CR+LF sequence, but that sequence will have been mapped to a single new-line character by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is just line continuation. In this case it helps us define a string on multiple lines to make it more readable. The macro will replace REGISTRER_DEVICE with `"{\"Type\":1,\"Uid..` but this would not be easy for you or any other reader of the code to parse.

Comment: That is to say that if I don't use the \, I should write everything in a single string. Am I right?

Comment: @RodRomo If it is not a preprosessor directive, you can just put string literals one after the other, and compiler combines them:  `"foo" "BAR"` is compiled the same as `"fooBAR"`, and instead of spaces you can put newline between.

Comment: @RodRomo what @hyde says is more accurate. A string literal may be split with spaces and as `\` allows for line continuation here we can also split it into multiple lines. The string literal will be the same no matter how many spaces you have outside the quotes